# Using mySQL with React : Questions and CORS problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, request, cors

I'm trying to access my mySQL data in my react app. For this, i use 2 files :

For react :

```
var request = require("request");
var option = {
    url : 'http://localhost:3001/test',
    headers : {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    },
    json : true,
    body : {
        option : "myoption"
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    method :"GET"
};

request(option, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log('body:', body);
});
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

For SQL :

```
function create_connect(){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'site'
    });
    connection.connect();
    console.log("connected");
    return connection;
}

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
var connection = create_connect();
console.log(req.body);

connection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function (error, results, fields) {
  console.log(error);
    console.log(results);
    console.log(fields);
  res.send(results)
});

connection.end();
});
app.listen(3001, () => {
 console.log('Launched');
});
```

However, i get `"Error: Invalid value for opts.mode"` when i put the "mode:'cors'" or "mode:'no-cors'" and 
`"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`"

when i don't. How do i fix this ?

Also, I used the right syntax the get the body.option right ? And is the `res.send(result)` caught by `console.log("body":body)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `node.js` application you need to enable CORS. If you are using `express.js` you could do that by using [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) lirbary

`npm install cors`

And then enable all CORS requests:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

In production you will want to restrict CORS request only from your domain.

More information about CORS you can found on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).